# Google's Geolocation API and "My Location" feature

Tags: google-maps, mobile, geolocation, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to find out and can not find an answer...

While using Google's Geolocation API in my mobile application, can I use the "My Location" feature?
or, in other words, can I use the the Geolocation API to find a phone's location **without** GPS?

Many many thanx

Ran

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, **Yes**

I don't have GPS on my Nokia, and My Location on Google Maps works fine.

So, I consider it proven by experiment.

Comment: Goran thanx but I know it works if Google maps is installed.
The question is, is the "My Location" feature accessible thru the programmable Geolocation API

Comment: @ranabra: My point was if it works for Google Maps, i don't see any reason why it wouldn't for Geolocation API - it means that it is possible to get coordinates without GPS. Of course, the only way to really find out is to try.